# livequery not always live when used with jquery.validate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, xval, jquery

I use jquerylive plugin to add additional css classes to .field-validation-error class like this:

```
$(".field-validation-error").livequery(function () { 
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-error ui-corner-all'); 
});
```

when I get some spans with this class generated by jquery.validate the above code works, but at 2nd validation it doesn't.

**here is the live link:**  http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/person
click on create after click save to get validation messages and click again on save

Comment: you are using JQuery 1.4.2. then why are you not using .live() method instead of livequery? http://api.jquery.com/live/ The livequery plugin has been integrated into the jquery code in 1.4

Comment: @Shree because I don't have events

Comment: Is there a reason that this can't all be done with CSS?  Why can't span.field-validation-error be set to use ui-state-error's properties?

Comment: the problem is not with livequery at all, but with the fact that the errors are only generated one time and are then reset and reused, so you lose the new classes livequery added.

Comment: @nathan gonzalez so is there a solution ?

Comment: @omu, i think the closest thing to a solution is going to be chao's.  you need to hook into the save button's click event and either add your classes everytime or make sure the spans get destroyed before the validation occurs.  either that, or change 1 line in your 3rd party script. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not hook your function into the same event that triggers validate()?

**Update**

I read the other comments and saw you were using xVal, read up a bit on jQuery.Validate as well. jQuery.Validate ties in with many events and registering on the event handlers would be messy. The reason that livequery works first time is that the labels are generated if they don't previously exist so that creation event makes the function run, everytime after this the label is just hidden/shown so it doesn't get triggered again but jQuery.validate's showLabel function resets the classes.

The ideal place is in xVal by making one small change in the `xVal.jquery.validate.js` file. In the `_ensureFormIsMarkedForValidation` method are the lines:

```
ensureFormIsMarkedForValidation: function(formElement, options) {
        if (!formElement.data("isMarkedForValidation")) {
            formElement.data("isMarkedForValidation", true);
            var validationOptions = {
                errorClass: "field-validation-error",
```

All you should need to do is change errorClass to:

```
errorClass: "field-validation-error ui-state-error ui-corner-all",
```

This is because xVal is doing the setting up of the validate plugin.

Comment: Had another look at the problem and it's not quite so easy to hook into the same place, updated with something that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just the the errorClass option?

```
$(".selector").validate({
   errorClass: "field-validation-error ui-state-error ui-corner-all"
})
```

Or maybe:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
   errorClass: "field-validation-error ui-state-error ui-corner-all"
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this without modifying 3rd party scripts. I'm using xVal which is doing all this for me. But if nothing else helps this could also be a solution +1

Comment: So your saying that `$(".selector").validate();` is called some where that you don't want to edit?